# Send signal to previous activity without finish

Tags: android, animation, transition

Is there any way that foreground activity send some signal (such as callback) to the previous activity without finishing foreground activity?

I am implementing activity transition on my own. Once user clicks one of images on activity A, activity B is launched with the bitmap, position and dimension of the image. The original image from A is hidden, and activity B animates imageview with the bitmap at the exact location in the exact size. So it seems the image from A moves. Simple.

But the problem is, there is very small time gap between hiding image from A, and start drawing image at B, so there is some flickering. Although I am currently hiding image from A after 100ms, I don't think that's good solution overall.

Is there any way that activity B can notify activity A just right before animation starts in order to hide original image properly?

Comment: If you must do this on different parts, you can then try using fragments, essentially you can lazy load the fragment and swap it. But again, does seem to want to jump a big fence that you can just walk around it. Perhaps you need to add a bit more details as of why you are constraint to do it this way to understand your situation.

Comment: Hmm. In your case, you want to hide the image in Activity A before Activity B comes in, Is that correct? If so, then do so, hide it then send then Intent. You can even use a crossfade animation to make it smoother, and when animation finishes, you send the intent or swap fragments. http://developer.android.com/training/animation/crossfade.html

Answer (score 0):

Simple, do not use different activities for this. Instead use animations.
Here's a simple example to translate and scale an ImageView:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ImageView ivImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        ivImage.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.background));
        ivImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                animate();
            }
        });
    }

    private void animate() {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.bitmap_movement);
        ivImage.startAnimation(animation);
    }

}
```

bitmap_movement.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.5"
        android:toYScale="0.5" />

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="240" />
</set>
```

Layout main_activity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Oh I know, but take into consideration that the delay will ALWAYS be there, since you are fighting against loading resources, when you create a new activity and launch it, Android has to handle quite a number of calls and then open the new activity, run some other methods such as onCreate and redraw. It's better to do the movement within the same activity. Optimizing it, is not impossible, but complicated. Not sure you want to do that.

Comment: I just wanted to know is there a way to send message back to previous activity. If you are not sure, then you should ask me specify it, rather than giving me wrong example.

Comment: Activities that are not in the foreground may be killed any moment. So this approach CAN be done but it's not guaranteed. Take a look into http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html